# how Database software communicate with other programs?

Tags: database, operating-system, pipe, ipc, software-design

I wonder how the database software like `MSQL, Oracle and MySql` communicate with other programs like `php programs` or `java programs`. How they grab the query sent from another process or program ? I want to know if they use `pipes` and `dups` provided by the operating system for `IPC` or they use another method outside of operating system ?

**NOTE:**

I am not asking how to connect to database that's obvious to me. I am asking how the two process communicate in the operating system between each other.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this two doc can help i think:

http://windowsitpro.com/security/how-does-client-talk-sql-server-what-net-lib-what-network-protocols-are-used-what-net-libs-

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/layers.htm#NETAG206